# What is "ia" in a Google Earth Engine feature collection? (Error when saving js script)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to display a polygon with a transparent fill using js in the code editor. I am following Noel Gorelick's answer in this question:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470500/set-fill-color-of-vector-polygon-layer-to-transparent-in-google-earth-engine

Here is his code:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-106, 38, -106, 33, -96, 33, -96, 38])
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(geometry))
var styled = fc.style({fillColor: "#00000000"})
Map.addLayer(styled)
```

The script does exactly what I want, however when I try to save it I get the following error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ia')

I tried to isolate the offending line and found I get the same error with just the first line:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([-106, 38, -106, 33, -96, 33, -96, 38])
```

What is 'ia' in a geometry, and how could I set it?